# Index 0 beyond bounds for empty array when calling addObject?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray which I am initializing like this:

```
self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

At this point, the array is empty. So, I add an object like this:

```
NSString *string = @"Item one";
[self.items addObject:string];
```

But the app crashes and throws the exception:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -    [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3460b3e7 0x3c306963 0x34556ef9 0xad7d 0x36465569 0x3644a391 0x36461827 0x3641d8c7 0x361c9513 0x361c90b5 0x361c9fd9 0x361c99c3 0x361c97d5 0x3642393f 0x345e0941 0x345dec39 0x345def93 0x3455223d 0x345520c9 0x3813133b 0x3646e2b9 0x7a15 0x3c733b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

My question is, I already know the array is empty, so why is it crashing when I'm only trying to populate it?

Comment: That's because you misspelled string in the first line.

Comment: Are you certain that `addObject` is triggering the exception? Your error indicates it's happening on an `objectAtIndex` call.

Comment: The error is not from calling `addObject:`.

Comment: You need to show more code and put this in context. Where is the error occurring? You won't get that error until you try to get an item from the array.

Comment: I know it seems as though the error is from reading objects from the array, however, never in the code do I call [self.items objectAtIndex:]. That's what's so confusing to me.

Comment: I copy your code and no error, NSLog OK. Check all your code and use break point.

Comment: Do you have a setter method for items?  Somewhere, somehow, you ARE reading from the array if you get this exception.

Comment: Of course, it doesn't have to be the "items" array -- the exception could be on an entirely different one.  Set an exception breakpoint so that you can see the call stack when an exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

**The exception says it all**, There are no errors in the code you have posted here. Carefully **go through the exception**.

```
 **[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]**: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

It is not because of `[self.items addObject:string];`
Check your code once again.
You are calling `[self.items objectAtIndex:0]` somewhere in your code when the items array is empty.